# make JList Visible even if there isn't anything to display

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment which requires the use of `JList`.

Basically it is an ordering shopping cart. I have 2 lists: one which has all of the items available to be purchased, and a second which holds the items that are "added" to the cart. It all works pretty well. However, I am having a tough time figuring out how to display the empty cart list when there aren't any items in it yet. I have an empty `Panel` until it's filled.

How can I make it visible all the time?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a solution for the problem your asking, coz i need the same feature.

I sought tutorials and it pointed me [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node144.html#SECTION000123100000000000000). ***Basically you just add your list to the viewport of a JScrollPane***. It works for me. Try to test and run the code shown on my given link.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the default sizes and visible row count.

```
JList jlist = new JList(model);
jlist.setVisibleRowCount(10);
jlist.setFixedCellHeight(15);
jlist.setFixedCellWidth(100);
```